# How to show files/folders sync status in GIT repository (using icon overlays) as shown in Dropbox?

Tags: git

While using Dropbox, the sync status is shown by mark on the file/folder itself (e.g. not synced is shown by red AND sync complete is shown green). I have also seen that some GIT GUI also provides such feature showing different marks for different status of files/folders. e.g. Committed, Untracked, Synced, etc. are shown with different symbols shown on the files/folders itself (as icon overlays). Can someone tell how to enable that feature for GIT repositories?

**EDIT:**
I am using Windows 7.

Comment: "Git" doesn't provide any such feature.  However, many GUI client wrappers for GIT (include e-git in Eclipse, or GitX) do.  Q: What's your platform?  Q: Have you looked at any GUI Git clients?

Comment: "on the file/folder itself" — That's in some GUI representation of the file or folder. You need to tell us what GUI you are using to look at it. The answer will be very different for zsh, Windows Explorer and OS X Finder. (It would probably be a tool recommendation though which would be off-topic for Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows OS there is a software called TortoiseGit that have this feature.
https://tortoisegit.org